# How to write output php variable in curl request in Postfields

Tags: php, json, curl

I am creating plugin and I need to get data using curl request. Here is my code

```
$userName = 'admin';
$password = '123456';

$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt_array($curl, [
CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => false,
CURLOPT_URL => "https://apis.tcscourier.com/production/v1/cod/create-order",
CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 60,
CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "POST",
CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => "
{\"userName\":\"<?php $userName ?>\",\"password\":\"<?php $password ?>\",\"costCenterCode\":\"2705\",\"consigneeName\":\"Nabeel Khan\"}
",
CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => [
"X-IBM-Client-Id: 9b9fc7fa5fc4",
"accept: application/json",
"content-type: application/json"
],
]);

$response = curl_exec($curl);
$err = curl_error($curl);
```

But the $username and $password variable in CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS is not working or output. So I want to know how to output variables in CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just pass an array to curl and it does the dirty work for you:

```
CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => ['userName' => $username, 'password' => $password, ...],
```

Edit: I just noticed that you try to send a JSON payload, then you have to encode the data first:

```
CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => json_encode(['userName' => $username, 'password' => $password, ...]),
```

Comment: Ok I use it 
$book_packet_array = array(
  'userName'  =>  'printed.mobilee',
  'password'  =>  'qwe1122',
  'costCenterCode' => '2705',
  'consigneeName' => 'Iqbal Khan',
);

and CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => $book_packet_array but get this error { "httpCode":"400", "httpMessage":"Bad Request", "moreInformation":"The body of the request, which was expected to be JSON, was invalid, and could not be decoded. The start of an object { or an array [ was expected." }

Comment: Have you seen my edit? `CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => json_encode($book_packet_array)` should work.